# Regarding signal to noise ratio

Tags: noise, signal-to-noise

I had set up multiple receivers and I was recording the same signal on all of them. I then stacked all of these signals. I have read that to improve the signal to noise ratio, mean and median of this stacked distribution are used (with median being the better indicator.) However I was wondering if mode of the distribution is also used?

Comment: Mode has a clear meaning in discrete statistics, (most eggboxes contain 6 eggs) but what does it mean on continuous signals? I'm not sure it's even applicable.

Comment: I meant peak of the distribution(by mode), is it not applicable?